# Javascript: How to add class to element without ID and Class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newby... :)

I have this code:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to add class "nav" to `<ul>`
element to make it like this one: `<ul class="nav">`

Can you help me? Cuz idk how to use "**GetElementByClass**" right now?

Comment: It's `.getElementsByClassName()` - If you don't know how to use something, then you should read its instructions/documentation: [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: if there is only one UL: document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].classList.add("nav")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu > ul').classList.add('nav');
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I did was just select the relevant `<ul />` tag with CSS, and then I added a class using Javascript's `classList` API.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I select just this element in all code? Only for this one, in this row  ```<div class="menu">```?

Comment: What do you mean? You can select this element with any CSS selector you want, as long as its valid.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the only of first ul on the page? If so, you can use this code

```
document.querySelector('ul').classList.add("nav")
```